# PHP isset variable than jquery and javascript should work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to know if my php variable does not exists, then I want to execute my javascript.

For example-

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['myVar'])){
   ?>
   <script>
   alert('variable not exist');
   </script>
   <?php
}
?>
```

Is this right way to use javascript code in php extension file

Comment: i think this is right.

Comment: yes its right way... have u tryied this code ..?

Comment: But why are you doing this? Mixing the server-side and client-side code? O.o

Comment: acctuly i tried , i just want to kow is that fine for my script to use javascript inside my php file , is there any alternate ? and thank you both

Comment: You keep saying that you want to execute your javascript "inside my PHP file"... if you want it to execute, this is incorrect.  This outputs the non-PHP if the expression is met and executes the PHP.  That said, this is off-topic b/c you're not reporting an error or needing something fixed, you're looking for your code to be reviewed.  Try running it and if you get errors or unexpected results, post a question.

Comment: if i need to mix server-side and client side code that what i have to do ?

Comment: You can't, really. The most you can do is call some server code from the client side with AJAX and return the result.

Comment: @Vld , are u trolling ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi are you? Because I just answered a question by OP.

Comment: @Vld ,please Enter it in answer,not in comments.So it will be Good for future visitors.

Comment: i recommend to you use `<?php if(): ?>` and `<?php endif; ?>` instead of your code

Comment: @MajidGolshadi ,what does it make difference ?

Comment: I recommend you only use $_REQUEST is you absolutely have to, $_POST and $_GET are better, IMO anyway.

Comment: @PratikJoshi ,no difference in code execution result but it's usual to use this code style when you want to write php code by other programme lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this and it will work:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['myVar'])) {

    echo "<script>alert('variable not exist');</script>";
}
```

Comment: is this a professional way to execute php and javascript code ?
and thanks for reply

Comment: no this is not the professional way. its a simple hack. I you want a professional way you have the save a cookie through PHP and then you have to check through jquery if the cookie exist or not or the second solution given by Rakesh(below). The error you were making was you were closing echo inside your alert script `alert(**'**variable not exist**'**); `

Comment: thanks for explanation, so you mean , if i need to mix php with javascript than i have to use cookies over there ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes but this is the easiest way to do. You can use this method. There is nothing wrong with this method.

Comment: no problem , the way to explain is really appreciated, now can you please suggest me how can i learn about magic methods in php OOP.. thanks once again

Comment: the best place is php manual though they have hard to understand language. You can try [link](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/9-magic-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I know all other answers solve your issue but i prefer it to do this way

```
<script>
    <?php 
        $isset = !isset($_POST['myVar']) ? 'true' : 'false';
        echo "var isset = $isset;";
    ?>
    if(isset) {
      alert('variable not exist');
    }
</script>
```

when php render your page it will give this output

```
<script>
    var isset = true;       
    if(isset) {
      alert('variable not exist');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How can u access =>    isset variable WITHOUT $ in javascript?

Comment: downvoter i think nothing wrong in this snippet,this is more readable then other isn't it

Comment: @PratikJoshi isset is javascript variable while $isset is php variable,i think you didn't see my snippet properly

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /var/www/html/sample123.php on line 4. This 4th line gives error =>         echo "var isset = $isset;";

Comment: change that line to echo "var isset = ".$isset.";";

Comment: @PratikJoshi which php version are you using

Comment: @PratikJoshi Can you paste what you have tried because i test this snippet in 7 different configuration and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try writing this piece of code where you want the script to be placed:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['myVar'])) {
        echo '<script>
            alert("variable not exist");
            </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You've crossed your single quotes in the `echo`

Comment: And how is this different than what OP has?

Comment: @Vld it actually is not different, but it's another way to do it as an alternative!

Comment: is this code is valid :-

 <?php if(!isset($myPages)){ ?>
       var arrayVar = {step:"part5", activationId:activationId};  
       alert('not exist');
       <?php } else {?>alert('hello how are you');
<?php } ?>